# maximum distance btw a number

Tags: python, numbers

i have got a series of numbers :7,5,3,2,5,3,2,3

in which I will have to find the average of the series and if that no. exists in the series, then find the max distance btw the average number found.

the output of the above series is 5.

//We have 3 inputs matching number 3 and maximum distance between 2 such inputs is 5

Below is the hint they provided.

//First, find the average,

then find the leftmost number that equals average no. and the rightmost

the number that equals average no. and the distance between those if there are >= 2 average nos.

Could anyone kindly provide me with a solution and expalanation?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the average or the mode? Because the average of these numbers is not 3.

Comment: Use the numpy library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def Average(lst): # calculate the average of the list
    # the sum() func returns the sum of all elements in lst
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 

def max_dist(series): # series = [7,5,3,2,5,3,2,3]
    # I assume that you want it as integer as it shall be present in the list
    avg = int(Average(series))

    i = 0, j = 0
    for i in range(len(series)):
        if(series[i] == avg) # leftmost occurrence of avg
            break
    for j in range(len(series)-1, -1, -1): # using range in reverse direction. More info in link in description
        if(series[i] == avg) # rightmost occurance
            break

    if i == j : # avg occurs only one time
        return 0
    elif j == 0 : # avg doesn't occur even once
        return -1
    else
        return j - i
```

You can find more about `range()` [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/)

If you have any doubts, feel free to ask in comments.